# How separate method calls with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, methods, refactoring

I use IDE Eclipse to wite java code. I have a class structure like this:

```
class Item
{
    private ItemId id;
    public ItemId getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
}

class ItemId {/*just some class*/}
```

I also have an utily method with restore Item by it ItemId, method has following signature:

```
UtilityClass.utilityMethod(ItemId id);
```

So, there is a lot of calls like this:

```
Item unpredictableItemName = ...
UtilityClass.utilityMethod(unpredictableItemName.getId());
```

or

```
ItemId unpredictableIdName = ...
UtilityClass.utilityMethod(unpredictableIdName);
```

I want to write new method, that will use already constructed Item object:

```
UtilityClass.utilityMethod(Item item);
```

So the question is:
**How to move calls from**

```
UtilityClass.utilityMethod(unpredictableItemName.getId())
```

**to**

```
UtilityClass.utilityMethod(unpredictableIdName)?
```

Comment: If there is not a mass number, you could deprecate or simply remove the old method. This will highlight in eclipse where the occurrences exist and you can tackle them one-by-one.

Comment: I know this way, but I want an automated one, that can do this instead of me. (one by one is really long and error prone).

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression text search and replace to replace:

`UtilityClass.utilityMethod\((.*)\.getId\(\)\)` with
`UtilityClass.utilityMethod\(\1\)`

And then fix the method signature manually.

Comment: It seems that after replacement UtilityClass.utilityMethod(variableName.getId()) become to UtilityClass.utilityMethod(1) so how I will know what varName was used (if there is some vaiables with Item type)?

Comment: Check that you typed the replacement string correctly. You want to type `\1` which refers to the contents of the `(.*)` in the search expression. It's possible you might have left off the `\`. This is why you are using a regular expression search (check the regular expression box in the search dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Select `utilityMethod(ItemId id)`, right-click, and choose Refactor > Change Method Signature.  Choose the options to keep the original method and deprecate it. You'll end up with both methods in `UtilityClass` and the callers of the original will be flagged because of the deprecation. Then you can use the regex option above or just use the deprecation warnings to migrate over time.

Comment: No actually that won't work for his case (I tried it, you should too).

Comment: @FrancisUpton, you're right, but it can get part-way and help migration. I updated the answer to reflect that. Please consider removing the downvote.